# How do I set an array size using an atomic variable in Chapel?

Tags: parallel-processing, chapel

In pursuing [A3C](https://nb4799.neu.edu/wordpress/?p=2929) I need to set multiple global and local parameters.  The global parameters need to have  shared size.  I think this means [`atomic`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/primers/atomics.html) variables, but it's still new to me.

```
var n: atomic int,
    x: [1..n] real;  # a vector of global size

proc localDude(){
  n +=1;  # increase the size of n
}
```

I understand the array will grow and shrink with the `domain`, but I'm having a hard time getting the semantics together.  Thanks!

Comment: With all due respect, are you sure, the " ***atomicity* "-of-parallel-operations** is the very property your code-design strategy is going to rely on? The concept of ( platform )-enforced atomicity of operations typically serves some other purposes, so the above sketched idea raised these concerns. Would be great to extend a bit the rationale, best on "destructive" operations, like on a case of many parallel **`n.{ add | sub | fetchAdd | fetchSub | write | exchange | ...}()`** methods, where having them protected by atomicity would enlighten the point of using such strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are a few things.

1. Domains take their bounds by value, not by reference. Thus, modifying a variable used by a domain to construct its bounds does *not* modify the domain ([example](https://tio.run/##S85ILEjN@f@/LLFIwU/BVsHQmgvETMnPBXKqDfX0/GohIolFRYmVClYK0UCpWIXMvBJrLq7yosyS1Jw8DZByHQUlKwUlHag6TaAs2DgDAsr@/wcA)).
2. Arrays *do* take their domain by reference, and so assigning to the used domain variable *does* make the array change ([example](https://tio.run/##S85ILEjN@f@/LLFIwU/BVsHQmgvETMnPBXKqDfX0/GohIolFRYmVClYK0UCpWIXMvBJrLq7yosyS1Jw8DZByHQUlKwUlHag6TaAs2DgDay5Us/Bq@v8fAA)).
3. Domains are not a supported Atomic type yet, so having a global atomic domain will not work. However you could use a [`sync` variable](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/primers/syncsingle.html) as a lock so that modifications are serialized. There is an example of this on the [learn Chapel in Y minutes tutorial](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/chapel/), near the bottom (search for mutex)

Comment: Love to see **live**-examples in action, Sir. The re-assignment trick, so as to inject / further promote the by-ref'd changes, presented in the **2nd** live-example might be slightly more emphasised, so as to straight attract the focus of a kind reader, might it not?

Comment: Addressing the part of this question about `atomic`, an `atomic int` can be used to define an array size just like a normal `int` by accessing its value using the `.read()` method.  Thus, you probably want `x: [1..n.read()] real;`  But @memorableUserNameHere's point remains true—that changing the atomic will not change the domain unless you re-assign it.